# Django Rest Framework fail on setting a new context to the serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django time:

I am facing an issue with providing a context to the serializer:

```py
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes = CustomUserSerializer(many=True,source='likes.all')



    
    class Meta:
        fields = 'likes',
        model = models.Comment
    
    def get_user_like(self,obj):
        for i in obj.likes.all():
            if self.context['user'] in i.values():

                return self.context['user']
```

in the view:

```py
class CommentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializer.CommentSerializer

    def get_serializer_context(self): #adding request.user as an extra context
        context = super(CommentView,self).get_serializer_context()
        context.update({'user':self.request.user})
        return context
```

as you can see, i have overridded `get_serializer_context` to add user as a context

however, in the serializer side, i am getting `KeyError:'user'` means the key does not exist, any idea how to set a context?

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessary and inefficient. You can just annotate with:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef


class CommentView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializer.CommentSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Comment.objects.annotate(
            user_like=Exists(
                Like.objects.filter(
                    comment_id=OuterRef('pk'), user_id=self.request.user.pk
                )
            )
        ).prefetch_related('likes')
```

In the serializer we then add the `user_like` field:

```
class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    likes = CustomUserSerializer(many=True)
    user_like = serializers.BooleanField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        fields = ('likes',)
        model = models.Comment
```

Comment: good, but if i need `get_queryset` to fetch every field in some instance, let's comment has description,likes, user fields....etc?

Comment: @Ghazi: no, it fetches all fields, the `.annotate` is about "derived" fields, in this case a subquery thus.